# Click with applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to automate the click in a certain position of the screen. I found several answers to my question, but none of them helped me.

This command should verify if "Spotify" (it's a random application, just to do a test) is frontmost. If that's true, it should click on a certain position of the screen (in that case, the position of the mouse is on the "play" button).
I run the program, everything is going ok. But when i put the application in foreground nothing happen. The program end with "Result: 1"

```
set x to 0
repeat until x is equal to 1
    tell application "System Events"
        if frontmost of application "Spotify" is true then
            delay (2)
            tell application "System Events"
                click at {720, 634}
            end tell
            set x to 1
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

I also tried to put some "delay", but they've been useless.

Comment: If _your_ application is in the foreground, then by definition any other app would not be.  System Events only targets the frontmost application, so in order to script the GUI you would first need to bring the desired application to the front by activating it, then get the name or position of the desired element relative to the front window (or whatever UI objects contain it).

Comment: of course I did. I moved the "Spotify" window so that the "play" button was placed at {720, 634}  (I forgot to add the coordinates in the code).
Before this program, there's another one that move "Finder" in the foreground. Then it starts checking if "Spotify" is in the foreground. In this case, I have to click on the "Spotify" icon and put the app in the foreground. At the end, the program give me "Result: 1" (so it worked), but the "play" button hasn't been pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative way: use python.

To install python, just surf the internet and you'll find out how to do it.

The library I used is "pyAutoGui".
To install it just look here: 
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Then, if you wanna use python and this library on automator, do like this.

1. Open automator
2. Find in the menu "Run Shell Script"
3. On "Shell" option, select "/bin/bash"

Then, if you wanna run your program with a third part library, copy that

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7<< "EOF"
```

insert your python program and then write "EOF" at the end

Here a little exemple

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7<< "EOF"
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(720, 634)
EOF
```